# Puncover: Stack column is empty after analysis

Tags: gcc, arm, stack, embedded, compiler-flags

I'm trying to show some stack analysis with [puncover](https://github.com/HBehrens/puncover), but it doesn't work -
the column "Stack" is empty, while "Code" and "Static" are visible.

I'm using an arm-gcc toolchain on an ELF file on an embedded target.

Do I need some compiler flags?
I tried with `-fstack-usage`, but that doesn't help either.

I invoke puncover like this:

```
puncover.exe --gcc-tools-base "Path to Arm-GCC-Toolchain" --elf_file "Path to elf-File"
```

The puncover version is 0.4.1.

**I fixed this issue by myself.
Topic can be closed.**

I had to invoke -fstack-usage to the compiler settings and additionally, I had to add --build_dir "Path-build-dir-for-su-files" when invoking puncover.